# pig - filter on AND function not working

Tags: apache-pig

This works: `filter A by daily_partition == '20150228'`

This doesn't work: `filter A by daily_partition == '20150228' AND daily_partition == '20150227';`

Any idea why "AND" is not being applied in filter?

Comment: I think you need to put OR there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies, `AND` evaluates to true when **all** the conditions are true. Meanwhile, `OR` evaluates to true when **at least** one of the conditions are true.

[image: AND and OR operators]

If `daily_partition` equals `20150228`, it is impossible that it also equals `20150227`.

> Any idea why "AND" is not being applied in filter?

`AND` *is* being applied in your filter, that is why you don't get any values. What you need for your `FILTER`, as you said, is an `OR`. You want to get the dates that equal `20150227` **OR** `20150228`.

You might want to read a bit more about [Boolean albebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Answer (score 0):

This is made to work by using "OR" function instead of "AND" .
I think the problem occurred because filter takes in the boolean input.
Any further explanation to this problem will be useful.
Thanks